# Copy shapefile to SDE feature class using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, data-management

Is it possible to copy shapefiles to SDE geodatabases using ArcPy? I have tried using Copy_management, but it says that it cannot copy between different workspaces. Is there a different function that should be used, or perhaps a workaround?

Comment: try CopyFeatures

Comment: That's got it! Mind putting it in an answer so I can check it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Copy Features](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/copy-features.htm) handles the conversion of file formats (shp into sde-fc like in your example) simply by what workspace has been defined in the output path.